# Ant task for selenium script

Tags: java, ant, selenium

I have written a test script. I am using Java, JUnit, and Selenium RC. I want run this script using an ant command.

How do I write an ant task and setup my build.xml file to run this new task?

Answer (score 1):

All a selenium test case is is just an extension of a JUnit test case. So all you need to do is just run a junit test case in ant. The ant manual shows how to do this very clearly.

Answer (score -1):

First you have to download ANT from Apache ANT. Then you extract that zip file and place to your drive. You have to set the class path and give the ANT path on classpath. After this, open a `build.xml` under the current project, write the `jar` file location in 76 line and write Suite name. Go to command prompt and type `ant compile` and `ant run`.

Answer (score -1):

I use the OnDemand service from http://saucelabs.com which absolutely rocks. Below is my Ant script for running my JUnit test against SauceLabs Selenium servers.

You can skip the `sysproperty` attributes in the junit task if you don't want to pass in any parameters to you test. Retrieve the parameters in your Java test methods with `System.getProperty("...")`. I do find it handy to be able to specify platform, browser and version from the Ant script and not hardcode them in the test cases.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project name="TestingStudieplads" basedir="." default="main">

    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="main-class" value="TestingStudieplads"/>
    <property name="lib.dir" value="selenium-2.24.1"/>
    <property name="test.name" value="TestingStudieplads"/>

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${classes.dir}" />
    </path>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" includeantruntime="false" classpathref="classpath"/>
    </target>

    <target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>

    <target name="run" depends="compile">

        <junit fork="yes" haltonfailure="yes">

            <test name="${test.name}"/>

            <sysproperty key="browser.name" value="Chrome"/>
            <sysproperty key="browser.platform" value="Linux"/>
            <sysproperty key="browser.version" value=""/>

            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
            <classpath refid="classpath"/>
        </junit>

    </target>

</project>
```

My directory layout is

```
Test
|- build.xml
|- src
|  | TestingStudieplads.java
|- selenium-2.24.1
   | CHANGELOG
   | selenium-java-2.24.1.jar
   | libs
      | dep1.jar
      | dep2.jar
      | dep3.jar
      | ...
```